# REACT JS: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, mern

I was requesting for some help with the below error which is occurring in my React js Frontend in my Login Form after Submitting required details inside the form.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

This is a screenshot Chrome of the error displayed on Chrome and the Chrome console [image]

It occured when I was trying to login after clicking the **Submit** button of my Login form but on my backend since am working on a **MERN App** it actually submits the data correctly and verifies it and I get a **200 Success message**, the screenshot to my VS Code Console. [image]

What I was thinking the error mainly was occuring on my **React Frontend** and my backened was running smoothly, I tried looking about the error on the Internet and could not get the specific fix for it but it had to do with a **try and catch** to fix it but did not workout successfully on my end.

The code below is the specific code on my Login.js which is bringing the error.

```
  241 |           password1: '',
  242 |           textChange: 'Sign In'
  243 |         });
> 244 |         toast.error(err.response.data.errors); //This is the line where React is complaining of the error
      | ^  245 |       });
  246 | } else {
  247 |   toast.error('Please fill all fields');
```

The Full Code for my **Login.js** file is as below;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import authSvg from '../assets/login.svg'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { authenticate, isAuth } from '../helpers/auth';
import axios from 'axios';
// import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Login = ({ history }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password1: '',
        textChange: 'Sign In'
    })

    const {email, password1, textChange } = formData
    // Handle change inputs
    const handleChange = text => e => {
        // console.log(username, email, phone, firstName, lastName, password)
        setFormData({...formData, [text]: e.target.value})
    }

    // Submit data to backend
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
        e.preventDefault()
        if (email && password1){
            setFormData({ ...formData, textChange: 'Submitting' });
            axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`, {
                email,
                password: password1
            }).then(res => {
                authenticate(res, () => {
                    setFormData({
                        ...formData,
                        email: '',
                        password1: '',
                        textChange: 'Submitted'
                    })
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                  // if authenticate but not admin redirect to / private
                  // if admin redirect to /admin
              isAuth() && isAuth().role === 'admin'
                  ?history.push('/')
                  :history.push('/register'); //Here for now am testing the routing with the available routes I have at the moment
              toast.success(`Hey ${res.data.user.username}, Welcome back!`);
                  toast.success(`Hey ${res.data.user.username}, Welcome back!`);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    email: '',
                    password1: '',
                    textChange: 'Sign In'
                  });
                  toast.error(err.response.data.errors); //This is the line where I get the React **undefined** Error
                });
          } else {
            toast.error('Please fill all fields');
          }
        };

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <div className='min-h-screen bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 flex justify-center'>
          {/* {isAuth() ? <Redirect to='/' /> : null} */}
        {isAuth() ? <navigate to='/' /> : null}
        <ToastContainer />
        <div className='max-w-screen-xl m-0 sm:m-20 bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg flex justify-center flex-1'>
          <div className='lg:w-1/2 xl:w-5/12 p-6 sm:p-12'>
            <div className='mt-12 flex flex-col items-center'>
              <h1 className='text-2xl xl:text-3xl font-extrabold'>
                Sign In for Ntuma
              </h1>
  
              <form
                className='w-full flex-1 mt-8 text-indigo-500'
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              >
                <div className='mx-auto max-w-xs relative '>
                  <input
                    className='w-full px-8 py-4 rounded-lg font-medium bg-gray-100 border border-gray-200 placeholder-gray-500 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:bg-white mt-5'
                    type='email'
                    placeholder='Email'
                    onChange={handleChange('email')}
                    value={email}
                  />
                  <input
                    className='w-full px-8 py-4 rounded-lg font-medium bg-gray-100 border border-gray-200 placeholder-gray-500 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:bg-white mt-5'
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChange={handleChange('password1')}
                    value={password1}
                  />
                  <button
                    type='submit'
                    className='mt-5 tracking-wide font-semibold bg-indigo-500 text-gray-100 w-full py-4 rounded-lg hover:bg-indigo-700 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out flex items-center justify-center focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none'
                  >
                    <i className='fas fa-user-plus fa 1x w-6  -ml-2' />
                    <span className='ml-3'>{textChange}</span>
                  </button>
                  <a
                    href='/users/password/forget'
                    className='no-underline hover:underline text-indigo-500 text-md text-right absolute right-0  mt-2'
                >
                  Forget password?
                </a>
                </div>
                <div className='my-12 border-b text-center'>
                  <div className='leading-none px-2 inline-block text-sm text-gray-600 tracking-wide font-medium bg-white transform translate-y-1/2'>
                    Or Sign Up
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                  <a
                    className='w-full max-w-xs font-bold shadow-sm rounded-lg py-3
             bg-indigo-100 text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:outline-none hover:shadow focus:shadow-sm focus:shadow-outline mt-5'
                    href='/register'
                    target='_self'
                  >
                    <i className='fas fa-sign-in-alt fa 1x w-6  -ml-2 text-indigo-500' />
                    <span className='ml-4'>Log In</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='flex-1 bg-indigo-100 text-center hidden lg:flex'>
            <div
              className='m-12 xl:m-16 w-full bg-contain bg-center bg-no-repeat'
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${authSvg})` }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        ;
      </div>
    );
};

export default Login
```

These are the **controllers** on my backend I was using for my **Login.js frontend form** called **loginController** but for the **Backend** seems to be alright since I got a **200 Success message** on the **VS Code console** as shown in the **images above**

```
exports.loginController = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  const errors = validationResult(req)

  // Validation to req.body we will create custom validation in seconds
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const firstError = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg)[0];
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: firstError,
    });
  } else {
    // Check if user exist
    RegistersignUp.findOne({
      email
    }).exec((err, user) => {
      if (err || !user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: 'User with that email does not exist. Please Signup'
        });
      }
    
      // Authenticate
      if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: 'Email and password do not match'
        })
      }

      // Generate Token
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          _id: user._id
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: '7d' // Token valid in 7 day you can set remember in front and set it for 30 days
        }
      )
      const {
        _id,
        username,
        email,
        role,
      } = user
      return res.json({
        token,
        user: {
          _id,
          username,
          email,
          role
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

After adding `console.log(err)` to my code this is the Output that occured in the Chrome Console.
The Error message displayed read

> TypeError Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

And also here is a Screenshot below to the **Chrome console.log output**
**[image: Screenshot]**

Comment: Use `console.log(err)` so you can see what it returns.

Comment: I added the console.log(err) right ontop of the toast and this is the error I got screenshot link https://imgur.com/undefined error message after consoling is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Good morning Sorrry seems this screenshot had an error think it was network but I had still uploaded the picture this is a resent screenshot for some guidance please https://imgur.com/PxfIN2F

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to check the data in your `err` object.

In the success case, you're checking `res.data.user.username`
Just try to look inside `err` before you are calling `err.response.data.errors`, obviously that `err.response` is undefined.

Comment: I added a console.log(err) and this is the Error Message that displayed "TypeError Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" I think this is what you wanted me to console.log right.

Comment: Good morning Sorry seems this screenshot had an error think it was network but I had still uploaded the picture this is a resent screenshot for some guidance please imgur.com/PxfIN2F

Answer (score 0):

Before passing your error message in toast, Check that by doing console.

```
.catch((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      // Request made and server responded
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the error as displayed in screenshot below  https://imgur.com/undefined I removed my .catch and replaced it with yours .catch at the end of my code this is what I got error says "Error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Good morning Sorry seems this screenshot had an error think it was network but I had still uploaded the picture this is a resent screenshot for some guidance please imgur.com/PxfIN2F

Answer (score 0):

This is **not directly** an answer and **anyone** is free to correct me since I am not a pro at React.js but because I managed to get a few things working thought I should post now my error came from the following;

First of all for this am using **React Router v6** in my code

First in the Routes I needed to have added these two paths;

```
  { path: '/private', element: <PrivateRoute /> },
  { path: '/admin', element: <AdminRoute  /> },
```

And second of all was to convert **history.push** since its no longer supported in React.

This means I had to convert history.push to useNavigate using navigate in the following way;

```
      ?history.push('/admin')
      :history.push('/private');
```

The converted code is as below not forgetting to import useNavigate like
`import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';` and then calling it as `const navigate = useNavigate();`

```
          // if authenticate but not admin redirect to / private
          // if admin redirect to /admin
          isAuth() && isAuth().role === 'admin'
              // ?history.push('/admin')
              // :history.push('/private');
              ?navigate('/admin')
              :navigate('/private')
          toast.success(`Hey ${res.data.user.username}, Welcome back!`);
        })
```

As you can see from my image Screenshot my **error** is cleared and the Chrome console is also clear and if you can **Zoom in** on the **URL BAR** you can notice the routes changed successfully from **/login** to **/private**;
[image]

Comment: I also want to thank evryone in the comments section with the various **Error Handling** solutions that made me solve this error, Am Grateful for all the Help.